# Compilation error due to table in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to create a chat programm for the TI-Nspire Calc via the serial port. So I installed the ndless SDK and nspireio lib to make the communication and it kind of works because there is an infite repetition of the message so I wrote this:

```
if(uart_ready()) {
    char input[100] = {0};
    uart_getsn(input,100);
    if(oldinput != input) {
            nio_puts(input);
            oldinput = input;
    }
 }
```

But when I compile it give me this error:

```
root@Kali-Linux:~/TINSPIRE/Ndless/ndless-sdk/samples/uart# make
nspire-g++ -Wall -W -marm -Os -c hello.cpp
hello.cpp: Dans la fonction « int main() »:
hello.cpp:61:14: error: affectation de tableau invalide
   oldinput = input;
              ^~~~~
Makefile:33 : la recette pour la cible « hello.o » a échouée
make: *** [hello.o] Erreur 1
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: where is defined the variable oldinput ?

Comment: Hint: use `export LANG=C LC_ALL=C`  to get your messages in English for the question

Comment: It's already declared at the top of the program

Comment: Thanks @Basile Starynkevitch

Comment: @TurtleForGaming: never comment your own question, but **edit your question** to improve it. You need to put some [MCVE] in it.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `oldinput`:

```
char oldinput[100] = {0};

memcpy(oldinput, input, sizeof(char) * 100);
```

Comment: It is probably already declared that way. However, you cannot assign arrays in C or C++

Answer (score 0):

If oldinput is also a char array,

replace `oldinput=input` with

```
strcpy(oldinput,input);
```

Comment: That assumes null terminated strings. That's seldom the case for IO.

Comment: More correct:

    memcpy(oldinput, input, sizeof(char) * 100);