# C++ UART Infite loop with the TI-Nspire

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, uart

This is a continuation of [Compilation error due to table in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746166/compilation-error-due-to-table-in-c?noredirect=1#comment80438460_46746166)

So this is my program:

```
#include <os.h>
#include <nspireio/uart.hpp>
#include <nspireio/console.hpp>

int key_already_pressed = 0;
char oldinput[100] = {0};
char voidlist[100] = {0};
/*
void messagel(void) {
    if(messagemode){
    if(isKeyPressed(KEY_NSPIRE_A) && !key_already_pressed) {
        nio_printf("A");
        uart_printf("A");
        //strcat(message,"A");
        key_already_pressed = 1;
    }
    if(isKeyPressed(KEY_NSPIRE_B) && !key_already_pressed) {
        nio_printf("B");
        uart_printf("B");
        //strcat(message,"B");
        key_already_pressed = 1;
    }
        if(isKeyPressed(KEY_NSPIRE_ENTER) && messagemode && !key_already_pressed) {
            messagemode = 0;
        key_already_pressed = 1;
        }
    if(!any_key_pressed())
        key_already_pressed = 0;
    }
}*/


int main(void)
{
   assert_ndless_rev(874);
   //clrscr();
   nio_console csl;
   nio_init(&csl,NIO_MAX_COLS,NIO_MAX_ROWS,0,0,NIO_COLOR_WHITE,NIO_COLOR_BLACK,TRUE);
   nio_set_default(&csl);
   nio_color(&csl,NIO_COLOR_BLACK,NIO_COLOR_WHITE);
   nio_printf("Nspire UART Chat by Samy. Compiled the %s At %s\n",__DATE__,__TIME__);
   nio_color(&csl,NIO_COLOR_WHITE,NIO_COLOR_BLACK);
   nio_puts("Press any ESC to exit and CTRL to send msg...\n");
   while(!isKeyPressed(KEY_NSPIRE_ESC)){
     if(isKeyPressed(KEY_NSPIRE_CTRL) && !key_already_pressed){
    nio_printf(">");
    char input[100] = {0};
        nio_getsn(input,100);
    uart_printf(input);
    key_already_pressed = 1;
     }
     if(!any_key_pressed())
        key_already_pressed = 0;
     if(uart_ready()) {
    char input[100] = {0};
    getline(input,100);
    if(oldinput != input) {
        if(input != voidlist) {
            nio_puts(input);
            strcpy(oldinput,input);
            strcpy(input,voidlist);
        }
    }
     }
   }
   nio_puts("Closing the programm.");
   nio_free(&csl);
   
   return 0;
}
```

The programe keep sending one letter continualy on the TI screen and on the serial output. For exemple if I write lol in the serial monitor it will infinyly send l and the letter will not change if I send an new string.

I really want this programm fully working for the end of the weekend so tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

PS: I'm french

Comment: you probably have not fully understand the concept behind strings in C/C++ might be helpful learn about them a bit more if you programming so close the actual hardware, just saying ;)

Comment: I don' have the choise it's the only way to make communication with the calc

Comment: Don't worry, but for this case here it could help you, the answer i gave might help you further.

Answer (score 0):

let us look this portion of your code

```
if(uart_ready()) {
    char input[100] = {0};
    getline(input,100);
    if(oldinput != input) {
       if(input != voidlist) {
           nio_puts(input);
           strcpy(oldinput,input);
           strcpy(input,voidlist);
       }
   }
 }
```

you are checking if the UART is ready if so you are declaring an char arry with 100 elements. Up to here fine. But what are you doing than:

```
 if(oldinput != input) {
```

you compare address of the array 'oldinput' with the address of the previously declared 'input' array.  I assume what you actually wanted was to compare the content of those two char arrays because 'oldinput' and 'input' will always be not equal to each other.

what you actually wanted is this:

```
if(strcmp(oldinput,input) != 0){
```

this compares the actually content of those fields. But be aware this functions assumes an null terminater at the end of the string!!! the same goes for the next 'if'.

Try to fix this and it might help you solve your problem.

[Strings in C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm)

PS: I'm German, but who cares XP

Comment: can you give me the answer I learn a lot with something that work

Comment: If i could i would but i have no means of testing the code, sorry. I use the stdperiph library at home and have no experience with you library you use.  I can only point out the most obvious mistakes which likely are the problem. 

But if you read my answer carefully i believe it will solve the problem of repeatedly writing the same stuff. Just think it through. In your version right now you conditions will ALWAYS be TRUE. that is something you don't want. you want them only SOMETIMES be TRUE!

Answer (score 0):

After poting the issue on github I make everything  working Link: [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/compujuckel/nspire-io/issues/6)